# Converting Map<Object,Map<Object,List<Object>>> to Set<Object> using Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a map `Map<LocalDate, Map<LocalDate, List<Request>>>` and i want to convert that to `Set<String>`, **String is id in Request class using Java8**

Request class

```
class Request{
  private String id;

  public void setId(String id){
   this.id =id;
 }

  public String getId(){
   return this.id;
 }
```

}

I know traditional way of doing it, but looking to achieve this using Java 8 options(Stream, Map, Collect..)

I was trying this, was getting compilation error

```
Set<String> values = map.values().stream()
              .map(dateMap -> dateMap.values().stream()
                    .map(request -> request.stream()
                          .map(Request::getId)).flatMap(Set::stream).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
```

Thanks

Comment: Show us what you've attempted, we're not a code delivery service

Comment: @LukeGarrigan, i missed that, added it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, create a stream from the map values and chain a `map` operation to the map values and then consecutively flatten with `flatMap` and finally `map` to the request ids and collect to a set implementation.

```
Set<String> resultSet = 
             map.values()
                .stream()
                .map(Map::values)
                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .map(Request::getId)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
map.values().stream()
    .map(Map::values) //now you have a stream of Set of List
    .flatMap(Set::stream) //now you have a stream of List
    .flatMap(List::stream) //now you merged all the streams and have a stream of Object
    .map(Request.class::cast) //you now casted all the objects, if needed (your title and post don't match)
    .map(Request::getId) //request becomes String
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: close but not quite. can you see how to fix your problem?. also note that a comment is with `//` as opposed to `\\\`. also, I think you should be collecting to a set implementation instead of a list implementation.

Comment: @Aominè I think there are several mistakes in my answer. It's actually I'm not good in writing code via smartphone  I've seen your answer, I'll upvote yours